# NavigationLock is not working with blazor .net 8 projects

Tags: asp.net-core, navigation, blazor, .net-8.0

In the previous version (.NET 7), I had no issues using the NavigationLock component. However, after upgrading to .NET 8, I'm encountering a problem where NavigationLock does not seem to trigger any events. To troubleshoot this, I created a new project using the standard template pages and implemented

I NavigationLock as I usually would. Despite this, the expected events are not being activated.

This is the code:

```
@page "/counter"
@rendermode InteractiveServer
@inject IJSRuntime js

<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>
<NavigationLock OnBeforeInternalNavigation=this.OnNavigationAway ConfirmExternalNavigation></NavigationLock>

 <h1>Counter</h1>

 <p role="status">Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }
    async Task OnNavigationAway(LocationChangingContext context)
    {

        var confirmed = await ShowConfirmationDialogAsync();
        if (!confirmed)
        {
            context.PreventNavigation();
        }

    }

    private async Task<bool> ShowConfirmationDialogAsync()
    {
        var s = await js.InvokeAsync<bool>("confirm", "Caught this navigation event! Do you want to continue?");
        return s;
    }
}
```

Can you help me?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I created a new project using the standard template

You need to define which options you used.  It's important.

I'm guessing you chose the *interactivity* location as "Per page/component": this answer is based on that assumption.

When you choose "Per page/component" `App`, `Router`, `MainLayout` all run in static SSR mode on the Server.  For `NavigationLock` to work it needs to interact with and receive events through the `NavigationManager` from the `Router`.  The router and Navigation Manager instance runs on the Server in the Http Request context [with a lifetime scoped to the life of the request], `NavigationLock` runs in the Hub Session context on the server.  They are different instances running in different scoped service containers: there's no connection and therefore no events.

For `NavigationLock` to work you need to move *Interactivity* global.  Try building a new application from the template, choose Global interactivity, and then re-test.

See this commentary for more detail: - https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazor.ExploreRendering/blob/master/Documents/Going-For-Broke.md

Comment: Testing with server + Interactivity global template get the expected behavior, that's great! I also think it might relate to the render mode but failed to find the document which mentioned it.

Comment: It will work in both Server and WebAssembly Global modes.  You start mixing them up and this, along with a lots of other stuff, stops working because you are dealing with different DI service containers.

Comment: @MrC aka Shaun Curtis
Thanks for ur response ... it seems that your expectation is so accurate ... i tried to follow ur steps by selecting auto + global but the page in Server Project appears for a moment then jump to not found... i'm searching now this problem before confirming ur solution.

Comment: Finally i can see the problem ... you can't get all benifits of every thing auto + global is not the choice because if i'm mixing the 2 types i'm loosing the interactivity ... to have the interactivity i should select one type.

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced your issue in my side with your code. In .net 7 blazor server, when I click the Nav menu to go to index from Counter page, or clicking  `<a href="/">jump to index page</a>` which I added in the Counter component, both of them would trigger the navigation event and I will get js prompt. But in .net 8 web app SSR counter component, both the action won't trigger the event, only if I using `Navigation.NavigateTo("/");` like what the [official sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-8.0#handleprevent-location-changes) showing could work.

[image]

So that I'm afraid we could only write custom logic by registering `RegisterLocationChangingHandler` like the sample showed in NavMenu component.

Comment: I searched this behavior in gitbub issue for blazor and I found [this reply](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/51436#issuecomment-1769323645), which points to the symptom shall be the expected behavior. and they also give [suggestions](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/51436#issuecomment-1775820094)

Comment: Thanks for ur efforts ... i coldn't reach a solution to trigger internal navigation event till now.

Comment: thanks for your response! and you might need to follow the suggestion provided by @MrC to use global Interactivity. My test and finding proved it's impossible to achieve your requirement, and MrC's reply gave an explanation along with a solution.